# I suggest adding an option to filter accounts by context

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

Any time I go to [my accounts page](https://stackexchange.com/users/2588467/johndoea?tab=accounts) I read a long list of accounts that aren't sorted in a contextual manner.

For example, it could appear as:

```
Mathematics
Seasoned Advice
Law
Unix and Linux
Music: Practice and Theory
Philosophy
StackOverflow
History
Retro Computing
Travel
```

### My problem

Such list isn't well organized and if someone is a member in many communities (say, about 30 communities) it can often be confusing to track of followed communities.

I would personally want to sort these in contextual groups such as:

> **Formal logics:**
>
> - Philosophy `(we don't have Formal Logics SE yet)`
> - Mathematics
>
> **Computing:**
>
> - Unix and Linux
> - RetroComputing
> - StackOverflow
>
> **Art:**
>
> - Music: Practice and Theory
>
> **Other:**
>
> - Law
> - Travel
> - Seasoned Advice
> - History

I think it would be best to let users create their own contextual categorization (in case they want to use contextual categorization).

### My suggestion

I suggest adding an option to filter accounts by context.

Comment: A "Create new group" button and drag and drop would be nice.

Comment: The categories would more easily be "Technology"; "Life / Arts"; "Culture / Recreation"; "Science; Other” which already exist at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones this has nothing to do with what I described - custom creation.

Comment: Your browser's bookmarks can already do this.

Comment: @Mat I generally use only 4 bookmarks in my browser. Why? Well, maybe if we drink tea sometime I would explain.

Comment: I think grouping them into the existing categories would be an interesting thing to do to help with the giant list. Custom categories, though, is unlikely to ever happen. Sorry, but the development effort involved in that is just not worth the benefit.